# JavaScript RegExp error

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following function:

```
   function checkRegexp(o, regexp, n) {

            if (!(regexp.test(o.val()))) {                   
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

This code correctly validates email addresses:

```
 checkRegexp(email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "incorrect email ");
```

This is supposed to check for numbers:

```
checkRegexp(numberId, "^[0-9]", "enter only number");
```

But I get this error: `regexp.test is not a function`

Comment: regular expression is not a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a string, not a regex, it should be

```
checkRegexp(numberID, /^[0-9]/, "enter only number");
```

Without the `/`, JS has no way of knowing you want that to be a regex.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a string instead of a regular expression.

Try:

```
checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]/, "eneter only number");
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you passed a string, not a regexp:

```
"^[0-9]"  // string
/^[0-9]/  // regexp
```

Second, I guess you mean `^[0-9]+$` since e.g. `"1a"` will pass now, which is not only a number.

Comment: +1 for the `/^[0-9]*$/`, but `/^[0-9]+$/` also could be an option. The first also allows the empty string, the latter does not.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Regex are the slowest kind there is</del> [Cached regex are actually faster than this solution](http://jsperf.com/numeric-checks). However, I'm leaving it here for reference :-). To test if it is a number, you can use this function:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/851498

P.S: other answers will tell you why your code is wrong, I prefer to show you a better solution.

Comment: Unless you are doing this lots of times, the performance difference is negligible.  It looks like he is doing it a couple of times maybe for form validation.  However, I agree that using a built-in function is probably a better way to go.

Comment: cached regex literal is faster (in chrome 17) even if you leave out `parseFloat`. http://jsperf.com/numeric-checks

Comment: Well, I'm surprised by this as I thought regex were always the slowest thing in JS. Good to know there can be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Something delimited by forward slashes (`/^[0-9]/`) is a RegExp object.  `"^[0-9]"` is just a string, which you cannot call `.test()` on.

Try this instead:

`checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]/, "enter only numbers");`

**Also**, if you want to make sure `numberId` only contains digits, you actually want:

`checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]+$/, "enter only numbers");`

Basically, make sure there is only one or more digits `[0-9]+`, between the beginning `^` of the value and the end `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You enter a String instead of Regexp.
This will work:

```
checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]/, "eneter only number");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes in the last sentence.

Try this:

```
checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]/, "eneter only number");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `/ /` or use `new RegExp("^[0-9]")`. It has to be a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object to invoke `.test` function

Change as below,

```
checkRegexp(numberId, /^[0-9]/, "eneter only number");
```